# Sencha Touch: [undefined] is not a function

Tags: select, extjs, sencha-touch, element

I'm trying to get element by class name with Sencha Touch

```
itemswipe: function(dataview, index, element, e) {
    console.log(element.select('.x-list-disclosure'));
}
```

but it returns this error:

> TypeError: Result of expression 'element.select' [undefined] is not a function.

Here is the full code block

```
var list1 = new Ext.List({
    flex: 1,
    cls: 'list_simple',
    sorters: ['firstName', 'group'],
    itemTpl: '{firstName} {lastName}',
    grouped: true,
    groupTpl : [
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="x-list-group x-group-{id}">',
                '<h3 class="x-list-header"><div class="header">{group}</div></h3>',
                '<div class="x-list-group-items">',
                    '{items}',
                '</div>',
            '</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    ],
    onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Tap', 'Disclose more info for ' + record.get('firstName') + ' ' + record.get('lastName'), Ext.emptyFn);
    },
    listeners: {
        itemtap: function(dataview, index, element, e) {
            console.log('node is tapped');
        },
        itemswipe: function(dataview, index, element, e) {
            console.log(element.select('.x-list-disclosure'));
        }
    },
    store: store
});
```

(Added) This is the generated elements of `{items}`:

```
<div class="x-list-group-items">
    <div class="x-list-item x-item">
        <div class="x-list-item-body">Melvin Gilbert</div>
        <div class="x-list-disclosure"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="x-list-item x-item">
        <div class="x-list-item-body">Jeaffrey Gilbert</div>
        <div class="x-list-disclosure"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like your trying to get .x-list-disclosure but you do not have it anywhere in the code you are showing us.

Comment: It is auto-generated element. I get expected result if I do `console.log(element)`. I wonder if the lib is broken, but I don't think so.

Comment: what is the value of `console.log(element);` inside your `itemswipe` listener?

Comment: HtmlDivElement with `.x-list-item` class. I added the generated item elements in the question.

Comment: Wrap your element variable with a call to Ext.fly and it will give you an Ext.Element representation of the dom element. The element variable is a DOM node rather than an Ext.Element instance. So it becomes Ext.fly(element).select('..')

Comment: It works, Stuart! Thank you so much. Please paste in reply and I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your element variable with a call to Ext.fly and it will give you an Ext.Element representation of the dom element. The element variable is a DOM node rather than an Ext.Element instance. So it becomes Ext.fly(element).select('..')